# Where do I get HM01 Cut?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have been back to the Parfum Palace to look, but I can't find it. Where do I get HM01 Cut?

Answer (score 2):

You can find it located at the yellow Poké Ball icon in the bottom-left maze section.

Source: [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Parfum_Palace)

[image: Parfum Palace]

Answer (score 1):

> Courtyard: in the southwest maze, just east of the center.
>   Go toward the middle of the shrub area to find a yellow Pokéball that contains HM01 Cut.

Source, [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Parfum_Palace) and [Thonky](http://www.thonky.com/pokemon-x-y/parfum-palace).